# How to get order_id in emails/create-new-account.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the order id in the file /woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account as I needed it for a function of mine.

I tried

```
global $wp;
$order_id = $wp->query_vars['order-received'];
```

=> this outputs NULL

ALSO

```
$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);  
$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
```

=> this outputs a total different ID than the order id that customer placed.

Comment: Sorry but you will not get any order ID in emails/customer-new-account.php as this template has nothing to do with orders notifications. This template is used to notify costumer when he create a new account. So you will never get any order ID. It will be better to delete this question as you have made a confusion…Sorry again

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Appreciate the answer, so i better be disabling the new account customer notification and create one based on status order. How can I disable this email. I am trying to do smth like: if (is_course_partner($order_id)) then disable new account email and send new type of email.